# Wildfly missing dependency jboss.ws.config

Tags: ssl, wildfly, wildfly-8

When trying to start up wildfly, version 8.2.0, using domain.sh, I get this exception.

```
    [Server:master-server] 16:44:53,818 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ws.config is missing [jboss.web.common.server]"]}
    [Server:master-server] 16:44:53,947 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
    [Server:master-server] WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
    [Server:master-server]       service jboss.web.common.server (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ws.config]
    [Server:master-server]
    [Server:master-server] 16:44:54,947 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 15339ms - Started 270 of 484 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 279 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

I'm trying to enable SSL/TLS. What dependencies do I need to add and where?

**Update 1**:
I've upgraded from 8.2.0.Final to 9.0.1.Final, hoping it would fix the problem, but it does not. I'm using full-ha profile.

Undertow Subsystem

```xml
      <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="master-server">
                <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SSLRealm" enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

Webservices Subsystem

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: what do configuration of undertow & webservices subsystem look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I've solved my own question after a few days of debugging. The script that's installing Wildfly for me changed the name attribute of server element under the undertow subsystem from default-server to master-server. Changing the name back to default-server fixed my issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For others who might face same issue:

There might be some issue with the configuration file standalone.xml.

For Example, the mentioned port number(s) might not be available.